# Software Recommendations Meta Stack Exchange is too big for SEDE!

Tags: bug, design, data-explorer

[Presented without comment](https://data.stackexchange.com/):

[image]

Comment: The main issue is that there are several Metas which still have "Stack Exchange" appended at the end, where this was fixed for other sites some time ago.

Comment: Seems like an easy fix...just knock off the "Stack Exchange" bit, right? As below with genealogy.

Comment: Yeah, every new beta site [from Beer forwards](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta) has "Stack Exchange" tacked onto the site name at SEDE.